# Почему процессор отображает 36 битное адресное пространство?

Tags: linux, железо, cpu, процессор, x86-64

При выполнении lscpu получаю результат

```
  Architecture:           x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):       32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:        36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:           Little Endian
CPU(s):                 4
  On-line CPU(s) list:  0-3
```

Объясните пожалуйста что значит 36 бит физический адрес и 48 виртуальный.

Нагуглить смог только то что 64 битную адресацию использовать сейчас не имеет смысла поэтому все используют 48.
Но откуда 36 непонятно.

И я всегда думаю что виртуальный адрес меньше физического?

Comment: Виртуальное адресное пространство процесса может быть и больше физического. Вообще, вы про [преобразовании виртуальных адресов в физические](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86) почитайте (и по ссылочкам там походите)

Comment: У вашего железа (процессора/контроллера памяти) разведено 36 адресных линий, больше оно адресовать физической памяти не способно. А виртуальные адреса на то и виртуальные, что бы можно было адресовать то, чего физически нет, дабы организовать замену страниц по необходимости

Comment: @Mike правильно ли я понял что у меня физически может быть использовано 2^36 байт оперативки, но виртуально т.е. в кодах программы будут использоваться адреса 48 битные, для механизмов подкачки и т.д.
И то и другое это зависит чисто от реализация в моём процессоре?

Comment: @Betflop от чего кстати 48 зависят я не знаю, от железа ли. а так да, все верно

Comment: @Mike, 48 зависит от железа (внутренней конструкции чипа, от размера адресных регистров в MMU)